# generate two arrays of randoms between an interval

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'd like to use a function that generate two arrays of same length but values of first and second array shouldnt be duplicates and neither values in first array shall not be in the second one.

What i've tried so far:

```
function generateSiruri(width){
    var exists = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < width; i++){
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
            var secondRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);

            if(sir1[i] == randomNumber && sir2[i] == secondRandomNumber && randomNumber == secondRandomNumber && sir1[i] == secondRandomNumber){
                exists = true;
                return;
            }

            if(!exists){
                sir1.push(randomNumber);
                sir2.push(secondRandomNumber);
            }
        }        
    sortAscending(sir1);
    sortAscending(sir2);
}

function sortAscending(array){
    var sort;
        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                if(array[j] > array[j + 1]){
                    sort = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = sort;
                }
            }
        }
    return;
}
```

Also, if you have a better option to sort these arrays with sortAscending function and a better option of if condition in generateSiruri please suggest. I can't see a better option now. Thx!

Comment: Start out with an array of `width*2` and populate it. Then use `slice`. Also, JS has `Array.prototype.sort()` built in, FWIW (you don't have to create your own bubble sort).

Comment: be aware that the `return` statement in the first function will exit the entire function if it runs - did you mean to use `break` or `continue` to exit/continue just the loop?

Comment: I used bubble sort coz i need to make a manual sort. Also, sort() function is not as good as newbie think. if i hurry i use function(a,b){return a-b} in sort method to return what i need.

Comment: Yeah, i used break sometimes but it seems like my condition isn't good :-?? Even if i use break instead of return. It is anything that i'm missing?

Comment: FYI : with actual code, a console would look like: primul sir generat este: 6,26,38,47,47,48,73,86,89,100
main.js:22 al doilea sir generat este: 5,8,14,16,19,31,35,47,65,97

Comment: as you can see, in first array i've got two values of 47 and in second one another 47. Isn't clear that if i have a condition that randoms shouldnt be already in arrays, randoms shouldnt be equals and second random shouldnt be in first array... shouldnt push the random in array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
    while(sir1.length < width) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
        if (sir1.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1)
            sir1.push(randomNumber);
    }

    while(sir2.length < width)  {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
        if ((sir2.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1) && (sir1.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1))
            sir2.push(randomNumber);
    }
```

This way, you're first filling sir1 with unique values and then separately filling sir2 with unique values that are also not in sir1.

Comment: Except your `if (sir.indexOf() == -1)` would cause a short array `(sir1.length < width)` if a duplicate was present. (hard-code `va randomNumber = 1` and run it and see how many elements you're left with).

Answer (score 2):

Given your comment, this smells like [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) so I'll break this down more.

Start out with a single array and make it twice as long as `width` (iterate `width*2` times):

> `var ary = [];`
>  `for (var i = width * 2; i > 0; i--){ /*...*/ }`

Then you want a number that's not already present in the array (we can do so using [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check):

> `var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);`
>  `while (ary.indexOf(r) != -1) r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);`

Then simple add your unique value to the array

> `ary.push(r);`

Sort it (your bubble sort is fine for all intents and purposes), then you probably want to return it back through your function. Here we return an array of arrays; Using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) we can turn the single array into two arrays:

> `return [ ary.slice(0, width), ary.slice(width) ];`

---

*Given it's not homework...*

```
function generateSiruri(width){
  var ary = [];
  for (var i = width * 2; i > 0; i--){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    while (ary.indexOf(r) != -1) r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    ary.push(r);
  }
  ary.sort(); // (or your custom sort method)
  return [ ary.slice(0, width), ary.slice(width) ];
}
```

Comment: Nah, isn't a homework ... it's a setup and training with js coz i came from as3 and i need to understand js methods. And atm im tired like hell to understand why thats not working...

Comment: Yeah, thats fine. I used a while before the if condition but i wrote here the method with if to understand better.

Comment: Anyway... your method looks great but i'd like to start with 2 arrays coz i want to concatenate them at the final